# Design for configuration sharing common attributes

Tags: c++, json, c++11, configuration

I have multiple processes having JSON configuration files. Every application have some common attributes with the others (e.g. log level). Most applications also have similar entities with different implementation.

For now, each application have it's own Configuration class, parser, serializer and verifier. It looks like that:

```
class Configuration {
    LogLevel log_level();
    std::vector<App1Entity> entities();
}

class ConfigurationParser {
    Configuration parse(const std::string& content);
}

class Verifier {
    bool is_valid(const Configuration& config);
}
```

The problem with the current design is that every application should parse/serialize the common attributes (code duplication), but, most of all, that the same constraints should be check inside the Verifier (e.g. entities should not have the same id).

Therefore I am looking for a good design allowing me to factorize the code and ensure that the common constraints are check automatically (e.g. if a Configuration contains entities, check that there are no duplicate id). I was thinking of providing functors (or functions) for checking the constraints but I was hoping to be able to apply the checks automatically if the Configuration meets some criteria.

Any advice on the parsing/serialization code factorization is also welcome. :)

Comment: I have coded something similar and implemented it around a templated 'master' configuration that reads and validates the 'common' configuration and contains as a member the templated type for the 'special' configuration.  Both of the configuration types are based in a common class (configuration interface) allowing the structure to be handled generically....